# Are questions asking for help in a formal grammar on topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

I was thinking of asking a question in which I show a portion of my language's formal grammar to ask for help in how to structure a portion of it in order to reduce ambiguity. Are questions like this on topic? My rationale was that creating a language's grammar is a key component of language design. However, the answers may be very question-specific and kind of like a solve-this-challenge-for-me question.

Comment: Relevant previous question: [Can I ask for review of a design proposal?](https://languagedesign.meta.stackexchange.com/q/32/133)

Answer (score 5):

### Teach someone to fish, don't just give them a fish

Can you phrase your question in a way that makes it about reducing ambiguity and just uses your specific problem as an example?